# Proper Way to Assign Delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here's my situation.

I have `ViewControllerA` and it is capable of loading `ViewControllerB` thru presentModalViewController. Now, `ViewControllerB` can later on push `ViewControllerC` into view. Both `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC` are the same class. How do I assign `ViewControllerA` as the delegate when I push `ViewControllerC` into view?

Currently, I'm assigning `ViewControllerB` as `ViewControllerC`'s delegate, which then calls `ViewControllerA` and I feel that this is not so right. Chain of command: `ViewControllerC` -> `ViewControllerB` -> `ViewControllerA`

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you feel it is right? Any object should only "know" as much about other objects as it absolutely needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the design is a little clumsy. Instead of passing the delegate back down the chain why not just assign the delegate of both ViewControllerB and ViewControllerC to viewControllerA (since they are the same class). You shouldn't have to pass up the chain unless C needs to communicate with B.

Before presenting the ViewControllerB:

```
b.delegate = self
[self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
```

in ViewControllerB before pushing ViewControllerC

```
c.delegate = self.delgate 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES]
```

in this way both B->A and also C->A

Answer (score 0):

Your design (C->B->A) is not so bad because it follows the logic of the UI flow. (You are not jumping from C to A directly.) Still, you could assign A as delegate as well if you prefer. Just make sure A stays in memory (with the modal view controllers that should be automatic).

Comment: even if it get's unloaded it's only the view of the viewcontroller is disposed of, not the viewcontroller itself - variables keep their values

Comment: @rokjarc of course but if A get's unloaded and C or B wants to place a callback to something that does not exist it will inevitably crash. I had this happen e.g. with asynchronous request.

Comment: @Munci: yes, you're right. anyway: it's only sane to make sure that something really exists before sending it a message if ther's even a slight possibility that the addresse could be dealocated.